# help with rle command

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble with an rle command that is designed to find the point at which participants reach 8 contiguous ones in a row.

For example, if:

```
x <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

i want to return a value of 11.

Thanks to DWin to I've been using this piece of code:

```
which( rle(x2)$values==1 & rle(x2)$lengths >= 8)
sum(rle(x)$lengths[ 1:(min(which(rle(x)$lengths >= 8))-1) ]) + 8
```

I've been using this code successfully to process my data. However, i noticed that it made a mistake when processing one of my data files.

For example, if

```
 x <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

the code returns 19, which is the point at which eight contiguous zeros in a row is reached. i'm not sure what is going wrong or how it fix it.

thanks in advance for your help.

Will

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to paste the first line of code in its entirety into the second:

```
sum(rle(x)$lengths[ 1:(min(which( rle(x2)$values==1 & rle(x2)$lengths >= 8))-1) ]) + 8
[1] 39
```

However, here is another approach, using the function `filter`.  This yields the same result in what I consider to be much more readable code:

```
which(filter(x2, rep(1/8, 8), sides=1) == 1)[1]
[1] 39
```

The `filter` function when used in this way essentially computes a moving average over a block of 8 values in the vector.  I then return the position of the first value where the moving average equals 1.

Comment: This is a great answer but FYI for any users also using `dplyr` you will have to call `stats::filter` so as not to be confused with `dplyr::filter`

Answer (score 8):

In the basic programming course I teach, I advise students to give proper names to subresults, and to inspect these subresults:

```
lengthOfrepeatsOfAnything<-rle(x)$lengths
#4  2  5 11  2  2  3  2 17
whichRepeatsAreOfOnes<-rle(x)$values==1
#1 3 5 7 9
repeatsOfOnesLength<-lengthOfrepeatsOfAnything * whichRepeatsAreOfOnes #TRUE = 1, FALSE=0
#4  0  5  0  2  0  3  0 17
whichRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight<-which(repeatsOfOnesLength >= 8)
#9
result<-NA
if(length(whichRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight)>0){
    firstRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight<-whichRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight[1]
    #9
    if(firstRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight==1){
        result<-8
    }
    else{
        repeatsBeforeFirstEightOnes<-1:(firstRepeatOfOneAreLongerThanEight-1)
        #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
        lengthsOfRepeatsBeforeFirstEightOnes<-lengthOfrepeatsOfAnything[repeatsBeforeFirstEightOnes]
        #4  2  5 11  2  2  3  2
        result<-sum(lengthsOfRepeatsBeforeFirstEightOnes) + 8
    }
}
```

I know it doesn't look as dandy as a oneline solution, but it helps to make things clear and to pick up errors... Besides: what if you look back at this code in 4 months? Which one will be easier to understand again?

Comment: Tedious to read if you're not used to CamelCase, but excellent for reproducible research. +1

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to break the code up into simpler pieces. As suggested by @Nick, you want to write code which can be easily debugged and modular coding allows you to do that.

```
# find runs of 0s and 1s
run_01 = rle(x)

# find run of 1's with length >=8
run_1 = with(run_01, which(values == 1 & lengths >=8))

# find starting position of run_1
start_pos = sum(run_01$lengths[1:(run_1 - 1)])

# add 8 to it
end_pos  = start_pos + 8
```